# ROP: System function not printing results to stdout

Tags: binary-analysis, gdb, system-call, rop, pwntools

in oder to solve a CTF-Challenge I have to construct a small ROP-chain. The scope of the ROP chain is to print the content of the `flag` file. I already constructed the ROP-chain, but it seems that when I call the system function with the parameter `cat flag`, the result isn't printed to the console.

My ROP-chain:
`payload = b'A'*80 + pop_rdi + addr_cat_flag + systemPlt`

As far as I know it should work this way, since it is a 64-Bit machine. But the strangest thing is that when insted of calling `system` I call for example `puts` then the content at address addr_cat_flag, which in this case is `cat flag`, is printed to the console. This means that the parameter is hand over corectly.
The address of systemPlt should also be correct.

Does anybody know were the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that in order to call `system` the stack has to be 16-byte aligned.